# Insert into from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
Insert into po_header 
(Code,Date,Status,Month_Period,Year_Period,Created_Date,Created_User)

(Select PO_PR from Purchasing_Default Where Defaults = 'Default PO'),
GETDATE(),
'Saved',
(Select Details from Lookup Where Code ='Month_Period'),
(Select Details from Lookup Where Code ='Year_Period'),
GETDATE(),
''
```

return error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Please provide the complete statement.

Answer (score 1):

Add Select statement before listed values

```
Insert into po_header 
(Code,Date,Status,Month_Period,Year_Period,Created_Date,Created_User)
Select (Select PO_PR from Purchasing_Default Where Defaults = 'Default PO'),
       GETDATE(),
       'Saved',
       (Select Details from Lookup Where Code ='Month_Period'),
       (Select Details from Lookup Where Code ='Year_Period'),
       GETDATE(),
       ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a valid data set before attempting to insert; can you write a single SELECT statement that returns all of the columns and rows that you wish to insert into your target table?  Without a better understanding of your tables and relationships it's difficult to give you more specific advice, but obviously what you're trying isn't valid.  However, something like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT a.col1, b.col2, b.col3
FROM a JOIN b on a.ID = b.ID
```

will work.

HTH.

Comment: there are no relations between tables

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by global variables as follow:                     declare @PO_PR varchar(50);
    declare @Month_Details varchar(50);
    declare @Year_Details varchar(50);
    Set @PO_PR = (Select PO_PR from Purchasing_Default Where Defaults = 'Default PO');
    Set @Month_Details = (Select Details from Lookup Where Code ='Month_Period');
    Set @Year_Details = (Select Details from Lookup Where Code ='Year_Period');

```
Insert into po_header (Code,Date,     
[Status],Month_Period,Year_Period,Created_Date,Created_User)

Values(
@PO_PR,
GETDATE(),
'Saved',
@Month_Details,
@Year_Details,
GETDATE(),
'');
```